# What is the most suitable node provider for Avalanche c chain transactions and assets tracking

Tags: blockchain, web3-providers, avalanche

On Avalanche C-chain I need to be able to publish transactions and track their status whether it’s mined/confirmed/dropped, furthermore I need to be able to track multiple account balances. There is a lot of node providers with event based solution that supports ethereum mainnet and testnet blockchains but I could not find a suitable node provider for avalanche mainnet and testnet. The closest one I found is quicknode but the event based solution supports just the mainnet. Is there any provider that supports both of the networks that I can check out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dev rel at Chainstack here.

[Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/build-better-with-avalanche/) supports both Avalanche mainnet & testnet. Based on your description (tracking the status of a transaction, assumedly through its receipt), all of these things should be generally achievable with basic JSON-RPC calls like getTransactionReceipt; this would allow primarily for request-based status retrieval like pending/null, successful, or reverted. (you could also wait for it after sending with .once in JavaScript)

Regarding "tracking multiple account balances," it depends on what you mean by track. You could just run periodic (in short intervals) balance calls through methods like getBalance on the addresses that you need; this would basically "track account balances." - unless you're referencing real-time (non request-based) tracking, in which this would warrant an extraneous solution like a webhook service or something of that nature.

Comment: As a kind reminder, non-disclosed promotion is against the rules of Ethereum StackExchange. The author of this answer is a developer advocate for ChainStack and does not disclose his affiliatation in the answer. I suggest you edit the question and start with the fact that you work for Chainstack to promote their products.

Answer (score -1):

- The easiest solution is to run your own Avalanche C-chain node for the testnet
- Also testnet is not needed; Avalanche C-chain transactions are quite cheap so you can use mainnet for testing